# Center div (vertically and horizontally) on large screen sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div (greenpromobox) which display's perfectly on my laptop and mobile screen's.

However on my large monitor it right near the top creating a huge amount of empty space around it.

I'd like to use % to keep the greenpromobox in the vertical and horizontal middle even on a large screen size.

**Live link:** http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="special">
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="boldme hidden-xs hidden-sm">Wish you were taught personal finance at school? We do too</h1> 
    <div class="greenpromobox"> 
    <h2 class="boldme">Aged 20-30 and frustrated with money?</h2>

     <h3 class="boldme">Take our free <b class="jumpstarttext">Jumpstart Your Finances</b> class to<br /> secure your financial future</h3>






                  <button data-sumome-listbuilder-id="d55c3ad2-17a7-47bb-9cf1-b16320caac27" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg-top">Start Class Now</button></div>


</div>
</div>
 </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.greenpromobox {
    background-color: green;
    padding-top: 1px;
    margin-top: 5%;
    max-width: 740px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.jumbotron {
background-image: url("../img/young-people-with-no-money-worries.jpg");
background-size: cover;
color: white;
}
```

**Notes:** I'm using Bootstrap 3.

Comment: can we use position property in `.greenpromobox`?

Comment: As you like @GauravAggarwal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your css by using flexbox

```
.jumbotron {
    align-items: center;
    background-image: url("../img/young-people-with-no-money-worries.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Puts everything into the center, including the h1 text, which needs to be further north. I think media queries maybe the only option.

Comment: Thanks I used this solution on a media query @ min-width: 1628px with .greenpromobox in a media query with a margin-top: -4%; 

This fixed the main issue, but then I need to push the H1 up, when I use margin-bottom to do this I enter a dance between the greenpromobox and the h1 with an ever widening gap between them is there a better way to position them?

Answer (score 2):

Try this once.

```
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.jumbotron {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple and most popular way to center align a div horizontally and vertically with position property

**CSS**

```
.greenpromobox {
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width:300px;//change accordingly or even not necessary to define
    height:300px;//change accordingly or even not necessary to define
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -o-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Above css will center align the div horizontally and vertically no matter what is the height and width.

> With transform property it is suggested that you should use prefix lile `-moz-`, `-webkit-`, `-ms-` and `-o-` it will support this property in all browsers

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, this works excellent on my large monitor but skews up on mobile as it shows over the top of other content?

Comment: use `@media ` query and change the css in smaller screens